# Convert byte[] array to bitmap with kinect 1.5 sdk in WPF application

Tags: bitmap, byte, kinect, emgucv

I am using kinect skd 1.5 and WPF application to simulate mouse events. To do that i am using kinect sensor. Hear i use depthFrames to get the distance to hand and track the hand. I have tracked the hand correctly. But to do the gesture recognition I have to use the gray scale image. I can get the hand using depthFrame. But it return the byte[] array.. Is there any way to convert this byte array to grayScale image. To do the gesture recognition I am using EmguCV for openCV wrapper. This is my soruce code. But when i converting,My bitmap opject->static members have error saying "Cannot dereference Expression.The pointer is not valid".. How can i do this process corectly. plz help me..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Kinect;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SkelitonApp
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    byte[] pixeData;
    private WriteableBitmap colorBitmap;
    KinectSensor kinectsensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Status == KinectStatus.Connected);
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    const int skeletonCount = 6;
    Skeleton[] allSkeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonCount];

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        kinectsensor.Start();
        kinectsensor.AllFramesReady+=new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(kinectsensor_AllFramesReady);
        kinectsensor.ColorStream.Enable();
        kinectsensor.DepthStream.Enable();
        kinectsensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
    }

    void kinectsensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {

        Skeleton first = GetFirstSkeleton(e);
        if (first == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        GetCameraPoint(first, e);
        //set scaled position
        /*ScalePosition(headImage, first.Joints[JointType.Head]);
        ScalePosition(leftEllipse1, first.Joints[JointType.HandLeft]);
        ScalePosition(rightEllipse2, first.Joints[JointType.HandRight]);*/


        using (DepthImageFrame handDepthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
        {
            byte[] handBytes = null;
            SkeletonFrame newskeletonFrame;
            if (handDepthFrame == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            using (newskeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (newskeletonFrame == null)
                {
                    return;
                }


            }
            handBytes = GenerateColoredBytes(handDepthFrame, newskeletonFrame, first);
            int stride = handDepthFrame.Width * 4;
            image2.Source =
                BitmapSource.Create(handDepthFrame.Width, handDepthFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, handBytes, stride);

             //Hear is the place that i have the error(nnn bitmap variable)
            Bitmap nnn = BitmapSourceToBitmap2(BitmapSource.Create(handDepthFrame.Width, handDepthFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, handBytes, stride));



            Console.WriteLine("aa");
        }
    }
    public static System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapSourceToBitmap2(BitmapSource srs)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap btm = null;
        int width = srs.PixelWidth;
        int height = srs.PixelHeight;
        int stride = width * ((srs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(height * stride);
        srs.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), ptr, height * stride, stride);
        btm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, stride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed, ptr);
        return btm;
    }

    private byte[] GenerateColoredBytes(DepthImageFrame handDepthFrame, SkeletonFrame newskeletonFrame, Skeleton first)
    {


       short[] rawDepthdata=new short[handDepthFrame.PixelDataLength];
       handDepthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(rawDepthdata);
        Byte[] pixels=new byte[handDepthFrame.Height*handDepthFrame.Width*4];

        DepthImagePoint rightHandPoint = handDepthFrame.MapFromSkeletonPoint(first.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position);

        int DistanceToHand = rightHandPoint.Depth;
        const int BlueIndex = 0;
        const int GreenIndex =1;
        const int RedIndex = 2;

        int handDistanceMax = DistanceToHand + 10;
        int handDistancemin = DistanceToHand - 60;
        //int handAreaDiff = handDistanceMax - handDistancemin;

        for (int depthIndex = 0, colorIndex = 0; depthIndex < rawDepthdata.Length && colorIndex < pixeData.Length; depthIndex++, colorIndex += 4)
        {
            int player = rawDepthdata[depthIndex] & DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmask;
            int depth = rawDepthdata[depthIndex] >> DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth;

            /*if (depth < 900)
            {
                pixels[colorIndex + BlueIndex] = 255;
                pixels[colorIndex + GreenIndex] = 0;
                pixels[colorIndex + RedIndex] = 0;

            }*/

            if (depth <handDistanceMax && depth>handDistancemin)
            {
                pixels[colorIndex + BlueIndex] = 255;
                pixels[colorIndex + GreenIndex] = 0;
                pixels[colorIndex + RedIndex] = 0;

            }

        }


        return pixels;
    }




    private void ScalePosition(FrameworkElement element, Joint joint)
    {
        /*Joint scaledJoint = joint.ScaleTo(1280, 720);

        Canvas.SetLeft(element, scaledJoint.Position.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(element, scaledJoint.Position.Y); */
    }

    private void GetCameraPoint(Skeleton first, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (DepthImageFrame depth = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
        {
            if (depth == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            //map a joint location to a point on the depth map
            DepthImagePoint headDepthPoint =
                depth.MapFromSkeletonPoint(first.Joints[JointType.Head].Position);
            DepthImagePoint leftDepthPoint =
                depth.MapFromSkeletonPoint(first.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position);
            DepthImagePoint rightDepthPoint =
                depth.MapFromSkeletonPoint(first.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position);

            //map a depth point to a point in the color image
            ColorImagePoint headColorPoint =
                depth.MapToColorImagePoint(headDepthPoint.X,headDepthPoint.Y,
                ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

            ColorImagePoint leftColorPoint =
                depth.MapToColorImagePoint(leftDepthPoint.X, leftDepthPoint.Y,
                ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

            ColorImagePoint rightColorPoint =
                depth.MapToColorImagePoint(rightDepthPoint.X, rightDepthPoint.Y,
                ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

            //set location

            //System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(rightColorPoint.X,rightColorPoint.Y);

            double screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
            double screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
            double windowWidth = Convert.ToInt32(image1.Width);
            double windowHeight = Convert.ToInt32(image1.Height);
            double x1 = rightColorPoint.X;
            double y1 = rightColorPoint.Y;
            double posX = (x1*100/ windowWidth);
            posX = posX / 100 * screenWidth;

            double posY = (y1 * 100 / windowHeight);
            posY = posY / 100 * screenHeight;

          //  System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point((int)posX, (int)posY);

           /*
            CameraPosition(headImage,headColorPoint);
            CameraPosition(leftEllipse1, leftColorPoint);
            CameraPosition(rightEllipse2, rightColorPoint);
            */


        }
    }

    private void CameraPosition(FrameworkElement element, ColorImagePoint point)
    {

        Canvas.SetLeft(element,point.X-element.Width/2);
        Canvas.SetTop(element, point.Y - element.Height / 2);

    }

    private Skeleton GetFirstSkeleton(AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        ////////////////////////
        bool receiveData = false;
        using (ColorImageFrame colorImageFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            if (colorImageFrame != null)
            {
                if (pixeData == null)
                {
                    pixeData = new byte[colorImageFrame.PixelDataLength];
                }
                colorImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixeData);
                receiveData = true;



                this.colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(this.kinectsensor.ColorStream.FrameWidth, this.kinectsensor.ColorStream.FrameHeight, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);


            }
            else
            {
                // apps processing of image data is taking too long, it got more than 2 frames behind.
                // the data is no longer avabilable.
            }

        }
        if (receiveData)
        {
            this.colorBitmap.WritePixels(
                   new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight),
                   this.pixeData,
                   this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth * sizeof(int),
                   0);
            image1.Source = this.colorBitmap;
        }

        ///////////////////////////



       using(SkeletonFrame skeletonFrameData=e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
       {
           if (skeletonFrameData == null)
           {
               return null;
           }

           skeletonFrameData.CopySkeletonDataTo(allSkeletons);

           //get the first tracked skeleton
           Skeleton first=(from s in allSkeletons
                               where s.TrackingState==SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                               select s).FirstOrDefault();

            return first;
       }

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to the question: How to convert byte array to bitmap?

```
    public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this byte[] pixels, int width, int height, PixelFormat format)
    {
        if (pixels == null)
            return null;

        var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, format);

        var data = bitmap.LockBits(
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            bitmap.PixelFormat);

        Marshal.Copy(pixels, 0, data.Scan0, pixels.Length);

        bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

I'm not pretty sure if that solve your problem. Please update your question explaining what method or line of code have problems.